# Rectangular pushbutton in vc++ gui which is bordered black

Tags: button, visual-c++, border

I have a rectangular push button in a VC++ GUI which is bordered black on the right and at the bottom. How is this bordering done? What makes this button bordered in the VC++ code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. You can choose which is convenient to you. Just to list out few:

1. Use bitmap button
   Create one image which has got desired border & look/feel. You can set this image to `Button` in your form. The steps to set bitmap to a button are:

OK.

```
//Define Button
CButton bitmapButton;
//Create a button
bitmapButton.Create(_T("My button"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_BITMAP, 
   CRect(10,10,60,50), pParentWnd, 1);
//Load the image from resource BORDERED_BUTTON and set it to button
if (bitmapButton.GetBitmap() == NULL)
   bitmapButton.SetBitmap(::LoadBitmap(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BORDERED_BUTTON)));
```

2. Create a custom ActiveC control for the button which will expose interface to set border color. You can find plentry of example on creating button OCX.